# ByteArrayInputStream throwing exception : No Serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: spring-boot, exception, jackson-databind, bytearrayinputstream

[image: Current Code]

Tried adding properties in application.properties

[image: Application.properties]

[image: Added Bean for Object Mapper]

[image: Exception]
Tried a million times to find out the root cause of the issue but still I'm not able to find the solution

It is throwing exception as attached .

Anyone able to find a fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need more code, for example, the `MockMultipartFile` and also the complete flow of data. Still, I will guess that you have an `InputStream` in your `MockMultipartFile`. If that is the case, try to replace that with `byte[]`.